# schedule backup Oracle

Tags: oracle, backup

I want to schedule backups in Oracle 12c. I currently work with Windows task manager. Now I want to do it internally in Oracle to have backups every 10 minutes. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to dba.stackexchange. Asking questions are great, however its expected that some research is done before asking - scheduling backups is a relatively common tasks, for which there are lots of articles and guides available through quick internet searches. I suggest doing some research of your own, then asking more targeted questions based on any specific issues you have after researching. Have a look through https://dba.stackexchange.com/help to help your experience of the site!

Comment: Why do you think you need a backup every 10 minutes? Perhaps you are looking for the [flashback feature](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm#g1026131).

Comment: As @mustaccio  mentions, you don't want to do a backup every 10 minutes.  Flashback is what you might want, but what you first want to do is ensure your database is in archvelog mode via `select NAME, LOG_MODE from v$database;`  -- and if log_mode is not ARCHIVELOG then enable it.  Then you need to archive your logs on a frequent basis (a few times a day) and do an incremental level 0 (logcially like a full backup) perhaps weekly, and an incremental level 1 (back up just what has changed since the level 0) perhaps daily.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, there is no such thing, as internal backup*. You either schedule an RMAN backup (and RMAN is an external tool, you can't use it directly from the database), or user-managed backup, where you are responsible for copying the files with some custom scripts. Whatever method you choose, you will end up calling some external script.

*Not counting the undocumented methods such as the `DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE` package..

But the actual scheduling can be done inside the database.

Starting with Oracle 12c, you can specify the `job_type` of a [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html) job as `BACKUP_SCRIPT`, and this actually hides the fact that it uses an external job, and you can use inline scripts instead of storing them outside the database.

Below output is taken from: 
[Scheduler (DBMS_SCHEDULER) Enhancements in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/scheduler-enhancements-12cr1)

First create a credential:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_CREDENTIAL.create_credential(
    credential_name => 'oracle_ol6_121',
    username        => 'oracle',
    password        => 'oracle'
  );
END;
/
```

Then create a job:

```
-- Create a job with an RMAN script defined in-line,
-- including an explicit connect.
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_job_name VARCHAR2(30);
  l_script   VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  l_job_name := DBMS_SCHEDULER.generate_job_name;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('JOB_NAME=' || l_job_name);

  -- Define the backup script.
  l_script := 'connect target /
run { 
  backup archivelog all delete all input;
}';

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
    job_name        => l_job_name,
    job_type        => 'BACKUP_SCRIPT',
    job_action      => l_script,
    credential_name => 'oracle_ol6_121',
    enabled         => TRUE
  );
END;
/
```

You can customize it for your needs.

Another example on My Oracle Support (requires a support contract to access):

[An Example to Schedule RMAN Backup Using 12c DBMS_SCHEDULER BACKUP_SCRIPT (Doc ID 2102623.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2102623.1)